# How to make S3-lifecycle_rule-Transition optional using terraform 12

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

In 12 version of terraform , if we define a Transition block inside lifecycle_rule, it is mandatory to pass storage class and days .

As per project requirement Since some buckets need lifecycle_rule with Transition  block , I have to add it in main.tf .

```
lifecycle_rule {
   enabled = var.test_bool
   id = var.test_id
   prefix = var.test_prefix
   transition {
   days = var.test_days
   storage_class = var.test_storage_class
}
 }
```

so for other buckets that does not need transition rule , we get error like - The argument "lifecycle_rule.1.transition.0.storage_class" is required,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make [dynamic block](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=terraform+dynamic+blocks&ia=web) to make `transition` optional. For example:

```
variable "enable_transition" {
  default = false
}



resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
    
    # ...

    lifecycle_rule {

       enabled = var.test_bool
       id = var.test_id
       prefix = var.test_prefix

       dynamic "transition" {

          for_each = var.enable_transition ? [1] : []

          content {
            days = var.test_days
            storage_class = var.test_storage_class
          }
       }   
    }
}
```